# MySQL query row/column difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that does the following:

I have a table that looks like this

```
Id    t
-----------
1     1
2     4
1     6
2     9
1     12
2     14
```

I need to find the sum of the *t* column for each *Id* of 2, and subtract from it the sum of the *t* column for each *Id* of 1.

So for this example, the sum of *Id* 1 is 19, and the sum of *Id* 2 is 27.

I would want the output to then be 8.

I would imagine the statement would look similar to:

```
SELECT sum(t) WHERE Id = 2 - sum(t) WHERE Id = 1;
```

But this obviously isn't proper syntax.

And I apologize for the poorly drawn table, I'm still new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN Id = 2 THEN t
        WHEN Id = 1 THEN 0 - t
        ELSE 0
    END) AS mySum
FROM myTable
```

Hopefully that works as-is... I only have SQL Server to test on, but the syntax should be the same for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`id` = 2, t, 0)) - SUM(IF(`id` = 1, t, 0)) as `result` FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how big is your table. If it is small or no indexes you can do:

```
select sum(if( Id=2,t,if(Id=1,-t,0)))
from data;
```

If you have plenty of rows and have an index in column Id:

```
select sum(id2)-sum(id1)
from (
  select 0 as 'id1', sum(t) as 'id2'
  from data
  where id=2
  union
  select sum(t) as 'id1', 0 as 'id2'
  from data
  where id=1
) as d;
```